# How can i make 16000Hz sample from 44100Hz sample in a real-time stream?

Tags: c++, c, signal-processing, downsampling, decimation

I use portaudio in a Cpp work.
My signal model treats the only 16000Hz audio input and

When the First released my work, I don't need to use 44100 sample rate. It was just about 48000Hz microphone.
So I resampled my signal like 48000 -> 16000 -> 48000 with a simple decimation algorithm and linear interpolation.

But now I want to use a 44100 microphone. In real-time processing, My buffer is 256 points in 16000 Hz. So it is hard to find the input buffer size in 44100 Hz and downsample from 44100 to 16000.

When I used just decimation or average filter(https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs/issues/186), the output speech is higher then input and windowed sinc function interpolation makes a distortion.

is there any method to make 44100->16000 downsampling for realtime processing? please let me know...

thank you.

Comment: Why don't you use FFmpeg's libav?

Comment: Actually I have found a good lib for my work. But some cases of them gave me the same result. So I wanna know the theoretical things and raw algorithm to fix my misunderstanding...

Answer (score 0):

I had to implement a similar problem in the past, not for audio, but to simulate an asynchronism between a transmitte signal sampling frequency and a receiver sampling frequency.

This is how I will proceed:

Let us call `T1` the sampling time duration of the incoming signal `x`: `T1=1/44100` and
let us call `T2` the sampling time duration of the signal to be generated `y`.

To calculate the value of the signal `y[n*T2]`, select the two input values `x[k*T1]`and `x[(k+1)*T2]`
that *surround* the value to be calculated:

```
k*T1 <= n*T2 < (k+1)*T1
```

Then perform a linear interpolation from these two values. The interpolation factor must be recalculated for each sample.

If `t = n*T2`, `a = k*T1` and `b = (k+1)*T2`, then

```
p = (x[b] - x[a])/T1
y[t] = p*(t-a) + x[a]
```

With a 44.1kHz frequency, `x|a]`and `x[a+T1]` should be rather well correlated, and the linear interpolation could be goood enough.

With the obtained quality is not good enough, you can interpolate the incoming signal with a fixed interpolation ratio,
for example 2, with a classical well defined good interpolation filter.

Then you can apply the previous procedure, with the help of the new calculated signal,
the sampling duration of which is `T1/2`.

If the incoming signal has some high frequencies, then, in order to avoid aliasing, you need to apply a low-pas filter to the incoming signal prior to the downsampling. Note that this is necessary even in your previous case 48kHz -> 16kHz